# neomodel giving Attribute error on save

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo, neomodel

I am running the following config for neo4j:

```
neo4j - 3.0.0
py2neo - 2.0.8
neomodel - 2.0.2
```

Finally, the code I try to run is:

```
class User(neomodel.StructuredNode):
    user_id = neomodel.IntegerProperty(unique_index=True, required=True)
    name = neomodel.StringProperty()
    phone_number = neomodel.StringProperty()

user = User(user_id=6, name='Sourabh Dev', phone_number='9711237840').save()
```

I don't understand, why I keep getting this strange error. Am I doing something wrong here or should I use py2neo instead of neomodel?

My traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/neomodel-2.0.2-py3.4.egg/neomodel/signals.py", line 25, in hooked
    val = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/neomodel-2.0.2-py3.4.egg/neomodel/core.py", line 159, in save
    self._id = self.create(self.__properties__)[0]._id
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/neomodel-2.0.2-py3.4.egg/neomodel/core.py", line 289, in create
    results = db.cypher_query(query, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/neomodel-2.0.2-py3.4.egg/neomodel/util.py", line 213, in cypher_query
    results = self._execute_query(query, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/neomodel-2.0.2-py3.4.egg/neomodel/util.py", line 207, in _execute_query
    results = self.session.cypher.execute(query, create_params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2neo/cypher/core.py", line 136, in execute
    results = tx.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2neo/cypher/core.py", line 333, in commit
    return self.post(self.__commit or self.__begin_commit)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2neo/cypher/core.py", line 288, in post
    raise self.error_class.hydrate(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2neo/cypher/error/core.py", line 54, in hydrate
    error_cls = getattr(error_module, title)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TypeError'
```

Comment: any workaround for this or any other library you used? I am using pretty same version of neo4j, py2neo and neomodel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two points here:

1. Existing Neomodel doesn't support the Neo4j 3.0
2. Cypher syntax has changed in 3.0, so the error raises.

In 2.x , MATCH **n** RETURN n
             In 3.0 , MATCH **(n)** RETURN n

Node n is enclosed in braces.